# What's wrong with my code(pointer)?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
void create(azienda *a, int i, int n)
{
    //azienda it's a struct
    azienda *ag;
    ag=new azienda [n];

    for(int h=0;h<n;h++)
    {
        ag[h]=a[h];
    }

    delete []a;

    a=new azienda[n+1];

    for(int g=0;g<n;g++)
    {
        a[g]=ag[g];
    }

    delete []ag;

    int j;

    j=i;

    for(j=n+1;j>=i;j--)
    {
        a[j]=a[j-1];
    }

    return;
}
```

I tried to create a function that would create space for a dynamically allocated structure. Despite the compiler not giving me any errors, it does not work! Can you explain to me why?

Comment: Was `a` allocated with `new[]`? Why use pointers and not vectors? This also isn't really a dynamic programming problem. At the very least, your loops can easily be replaced with `std::copy`.

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your function. Are you saving the old array `a` into `ag`, then delete `a` and then reload it with the old `ag`?

Comment: yes, i made this because the array of struct of a have N elements and I would increment it by one(n+1)!

Comment: You should delete variables in the same place that you allocate them, to keep everything organized.

Comment: I can't make a generally function that icrase the size of my struct saving the data that they store?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear on what you are trying to do. Are you trying to Increase the size of the array (by 1), and shift all elements after the i'th element, back one?

Comment: First of all, I'm trying to increase the length of my vector of structs, keeping the previous data .. second: I have to move all the values ​​from a point on (i) forward one unit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the main problem is that the pointer that you use as argument for the first parameter of function

```
void create(azienda *a, int i, int n);
```

knows nothing that it was changed inside the function. azienda *a is a local variable of the function and after exiting the function it will be destroyed. You have three approaches. The first one is to return the new pointer from the function

```
azienda * create(azienda *a, int i, int n);
```

and assign it to the outer pointer.

The two others use indirection. For example

```
void create(azienda **a, int i, int n);
```

or

```
void create(azienda * &a, int i, int n);
```

Take into account that this code snippet is invalid

```
a=new azienda[n+1];

for(int g=0;g<n;g++)
{
    a[g]=ag[g];

}

delete []ag;

int j;

j=i;

for(j=n+1;j>=i;j--)
{

    a[j]=a[j-1];
```

There is no such element as a[n+1] because valid indicies will be [0, n+1 )